# Why does println only print the boolean value

Tags: java

The Code:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="";
        System.out.println(""==str+"and");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
E:\test>java A 
false
```

there is not "and" after that

Comment: `==` is a comparison operator. Its result is boolean. Also, I suspect you haven't compiled the given code, as the result is `false`.

Comment: Could you edit and write a question in plain English ? (we are not computers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why only print boolean? System.out.println(“”==str+“and”);

Because `+` additive operator has higher priority than `==` equality operator.

First operation would be `str+"and"` then `==` will result of `Boolean` which is  `false`

```
"" == "and" ? = false
```

*Java Documentation for [Operators Priorities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)*

Comment: @FulndonRong You are welcome :) ... no dear just keep going and don't stop write questions...

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to print `true/false` condition then follow @JavaHD's answer

if you want to print `trueand`

then wrap your boolean expression with pranthesis
e.g.:

```
System.out.println((""==str)+"and");
```